# yml files to one

Tags: perl

I am planning to merge two yml files to one single yml file using "`use Hash::Merge qw( merge );`"

Here is my sample script :-

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Hash::Merge qw( merge );
use YAML::XS qw(Load Dump);
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file append_file);

my $yaml1 = "/home/test/one.yml";
my $yaml2 = "/home/test/two.yml";
my $in_yaml = read_file($yaml1, { binmode => ':raw' });
my $clkgrps = Load $in_yaml ;
my $in_yaml1 = read_file($yaml2, { binmode => ':raw' });
my $clkgrps1 = Load $in_yaml1;
my $clockgroups = merge($clkgrps, $clkgrps1);
my $out_yaml = Dump $clockgroups;
my $outFile = "clockgroups_used.yml" ;
print("Generating Yaml file: $outFile \n") ;
write_file($outFile, { binmode => ':raw' }, $out_yaml);
```

one.yml:-

```
emailName: David
emailAddresses:
    - sillymoos@cpan.org
    - perltricks.com@gmail.com
credentials:
    username: sillymoose
    password: itsasecret
```

two.yml:-

```
 emailName: Pranay
emailAddresses:
    - heelo@cpan.org
    - test@gmail.com
credentials:
    username: link
    password: sanity
```

After executing my script i do see the output of final yml file clockgroups_used.yml has following content which is only the content from one.yml

```
    ---
credentials:
  password: itsasecret
  username: sillymoose
emailAddresses:
- sillymoos@cpan.org
- perltricks.com@gmail.com
- heelo@cpan.org
- test@gmail.com
emailName: David
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Why i am not able to see merge of two yml files?

Comment: FYI, for next time you have a similar issue: using `Data::Printer` and adding a few dumps of the hashes reveals quickly that the issue is with `Hash::Merge::merge` rather than anything YAML related. This allows to reduce the example a bit and see what's happening. It's then fairly fast to look at the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge) of `Hash::Merge` which explains how to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the `Hash::Merge` module, add this line:

```
Hash::Merge::set_behavior('RETAINMENT_PRECEDENT');
```

The default behavior of `Hash::Merge` is to not change the datatypes of the elements within the hashes, and to prioritize the content of the first argument of `merge`. Setting [`RETAINMENT_PRECEDENT`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge#Retainment-Precedence) instructs `Hash::Merge` to keep all data of both hashes by creating arrays if necessary.

The resulting YAML file is thus

```
---
credentials:
  password:
  - itsasecret
  - sanity
  username:
  - sillymoose
  - link
emailAddresses:
- sillymoos@cpan.org
- perltricks.com@gmail.com
- heelo@cpan.org
- test@gmail.com
emailName:
- David
- Pranay
```

Comment: Thanks Dada, I have one query, If suppose two yml files have same key and its value is different. How it handles? Is there a way to override from selected yml file if it sees such conflicts ? Do we have any flags to set to achieve the same?

Comment: @RAMA You can use [`Hash::Merge::add_behavior_spec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge#add_behavior_spec(-%3Chashref%3E,-[%3Cname%3E]-)). I don't fully understand what you are saying, but I suggest you either clarify your question with precise examples of what you want to do (in the case 
 that my answer does not answer your question), or ask another question (if my answer does answer your question and this is another question).